# Object Type and Array for SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have my Student Table 
That has `student_id`, `First_name`, `Last_Name` , `Phone`

My Prof. wants me to modify the Student table and creates an obj.type called phone_obj with the attributes, country_code, area_code, and phone_Number.
Then modify the student table so the `Phone` column is an array of phone_obj. Then insert information into the newly changed `Phone` column for the student table.

First Part : I think I got...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE phone_obj AS OBJECT (
  COUNTRY_Code NUMBER(2),
  AREA_CODE NUMBER(3),
  PHONE_NUMBER NUMBER(7)
);
```

Second and the third part, I need clarification.

Comment: You need to `ALTER` the column datatype to `phone_obj` and then insert values as a `ROW` into it.

Comment: Column as array? Isn't creating separate table is good normalized solution? which can have studentid and phone number

Comment: Consider Me  - I am assuming something like this?                                            Alter table Student
Modify Phone phone_obj;

Comment: huMpty duMpty - I thought so too....but Prof wanted to modify that current  Student table  that's part of the reason I can't follow this.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty it is about defining and using a column of array type, not about normalizing databases

Comment: @PavelGatnar: I am not answering here, just asking a question!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your professor wants you to explore the one-to-many relationship. In your case, one student may have zero or more phone numbers.

So create a new table for the phone numbers. Let the table have its own primary key. For each phone number add a column with the primary key of the student who owns it. Consult for example this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-nov/o61sql-512018.html

As this looks like homework, I am not posting code. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

1. create object type
2. create array type
3. add phones column of the array type to the table
4. copy data from the old phone column
5. drop the old phone column